# Moving ArcMap layers with their symbology to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, export

I need to move my ArcMap layers to QGIS and need to have the same symbology.

I tried using the mxd2qgs tool (https://github.com/fitnr/mxd2qgs) but it is outdated.

Is there any way I can display my layers from ArcMap with their symbology?

I have grouped lyr files that can be inputted to ArcGIS easily as well as a gdb file. After inputting a gdb is appearing with no symbology (which is ok cos as far as i know gdb does not store symbology of the layers). I would like to see these grouped layers (.lyr) in QGIS. It is a quite massive gdb file and tools such as Mxd2qgs tool, SLYR, Arcmap2sld tool or Arc2Earth are not the best ideas as it takes ages to process even half of the whole dataset. I tried them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @katagena](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413179/moving-arcgis-layers-with-their-symbology-to-qgis#comment671811_413179):

> If you go here: https://north-road.com/slyr/, under the "Vector LYR
> file conversion functionality", at the end you can see this: As
> described in Open Source Pledge, this stage has been fully financed
> and will be included in the community edition of the SLYR plugin on
> 1st January, 2022.